# Finding Nearest adjacent point Recursively

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a dataset of all locations my phone has been. (I got it via Google Takeout if you are interested.) The problem with the data is that at a certain point, I got a second phone. The dataset I have doesn't have any information that allows me to track data by a specific phone. So if I leave a phone at home then it shows me at two places at once. I decided to write a query that tries to find adjacent points by determining which point in the last 5 are closest eliminating and point I had to have traveled faster than 150mph in order to get to.

The table definition for the data is here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[locationdata](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [t] [datetime] NULL,
    [lat] [float] NULL,
    [long] [float] NULL,
    [accuracy] [smallint] NULL,
    [activity] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [confidence] [int] NULL,
    [velocity] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [altitude] [smallint] NULL,
    [heading] [smallint] NULL,
    [point] [geography] NULL,
    [tag] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_locationdata] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The rows were inserted in time order so the IDs line up in the correct order with the exception being that the same time can exist for multiple points.

So here is my attempt at writing this without a CURSOR. The issue being that you can't use a "TOP" in the recursive part of a Common Table Expression.

```
WITH tripdata(originid, endid, startid, speed, distance, startpoint, startt)
AS
(
SELECT originid, endid, startid, speed, distance, startpoint, startt
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
               origin.id as originid
             , NULL as endid
             , origin.id as startid
             , NULL as distance
             , NULL as speed
             , point as startpoint
             , t as startt
        FROM locationdata origin
    )  a
UNION ALL

        SELECT
              originid as originid
            , startid as endid
            , l.id as startid
            , origin.startpoint.STDistance(l.point) as distance
            , (origin.startpoint.STDistance(l.point)/(datediff(S, origin.startt, l.t))) * -2.23694  as speed
            , l.point as startpoint
            , l.t as startt
        FROM tripdata origin
        CROSS APPLY
        (       
            SELECT top 1
                  z.id
                 ,z.point
                 ,z.t
            FROM locationdata z
            where origin.startid > z.ID and origin.startid -5 < z.ID
                and z.t <> origin.startt
                and  (origin.startpoint.STDistance(z.point)/(datediff(S, origin.startt, z.t))) * -2.23694 < 150
            order by origin.startpoint.STDistance(z.point)
        ) l

)
SELECT *
FROM tripdata
WHERE originid = 218255
;
```

I am open to suggestions on how this query might be fixed or if it is even possible.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I agree wit the XY problem but have other questions. Why 150 mph? I just wonder if there is a simpler logic. Also, is the end result to just track yourself? Do you always leave one phone at home? etc. I feel that this could be tackled in an easier way. Interesting problem.

Comment: @scsimon I don't always leave my phone at home and in fact I have left it in other moving vehicles too. This is rare, but removing these was a consideration for pulling out static position of an alternate phone. 

Yes. I am trying to track myself. I am doing a proof of concept to test some new tools. I will post a link when complete. I would love to see the solution to the query, but ultimately I just need the data right for my demo. If there is an easier way to separate I am open.